# Combing two arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays and I need to combine them into one array. I have tried `array_merge` , `array_combine` but it is not working. Can someone help me?

**First Array**

```
Array
(

[6] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 5
        [title] => YSL
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

)
```

**Second Array**

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 13
        [title] => ar
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 14
        [title] => bi
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 28
        [title] => lc
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 21
        [title] => gat
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 20
        [title] => testle
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 29
        [title] => test
        [field_category] => test
        [field_collection_creation] => 
        [body] => 
    )

)
```

How can I combine these two arrays, keeping the keys like they are?

Comment: What to do if any index is present in both?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: @Thamilan Does array_replace save numeric index?

Comment: @Utkanos  they don't save numeric index, i think

Comment: @splash58 Index will not be present in both arrays. It was one array at start and needed to be break down for some manipulation and now i need to combine then into one whole array again.

Comment: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) does that

Comment: @Thamilan https://eval.in/585208

Comment: @splash58 Since he told index will not be present, I said so. If he want to preserve index, then he should go for array_replace and if needed recursive

Comment: @Thamilan *keeping the keys like they are*

Answer (score 2):

Because *Index will not be present in both arrays* use an usual foreach

```
foreach($ar1 as $k=>$v)
  $ar2[$k] = $v;
```

It takes key and value from one array and creates the same key value pair in other array

Comment: Can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

Just merge arrays with array union `+` operator:

```
//  $first and $second - are your arrays respectively
$result = $second + $first;  // $result contains the combined array
```

> If you want to append array elements from the second array to the
>   first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array
>   and not re-indexing, use the **+** array union operator: